# How can I display top 3 products with its price and arrange by average prices?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have this records in products table with product_id and its price

| product_id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 |
| 1 | 190 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 4 | 513 |
| 5 | 157 |
| 5 | 147 |

and I want to get the top 3 products and arrange it by average price something like this

| product_id | price | avg_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 513 | 513 |
| 1 | 150 | 170 |
| 1 | 190 | 170 |
| 5 | 157 | 152 |
| 5 | 147 | 152 |

how to write/code it in sql query or laravel eloquent query?

Comment: Would you like the top 3 to be the products of the highest average price or the top 3 common products?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Neither one from your question is what I am asking, I want to display top 3 products and arrange it by there computed average prices.

Comment: But what makes something a "top" product?

Comment: Thank you for the response, it is already answered :) @ysth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH AverageCTE AS
(
    SELECT product_id, AVG(avg_price) as avg_price 
    FROM products
    GROUP BY product_id
)

SELECT p.product_id, price, avg_price
FROM product p JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM AverageCTE ORDER BY avg_price DESC LIMIT 3) a 
    on p.product_id = a.product_id
ORDER BY avg_price DESC
```

Comment: @PeterParker You're welcome spidey

Comment: This code works! Thank you sir @YuriyFaktorovich